# Guidance on how to generate JS Countdowns when mapping through an array of values

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mapping

I'm struggling to find the best way to display a countdown timer per item when mapping an array of values in to HTML.

I'm working on a project where I access values from an API and display them in a card format on my website. All the information displays as intended, but I cannot figure out how to display a unique countdown timer for each card.

Currently, I'm attempting to run a function at each mapping iteration that would generate the countdown and display on the id of 'countdownId'. This doesn't work as I get the error of **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'**. I know this is because the id isn't generated at the time of the function running, but I cannot figure out an alternative way to display an actual countdown. I've tried to research and it hasn't gone anywhere.

Appreciate any help in advance.

**Index.html** - Limited this to relevant ID associated with displaying all cards.

```
<ul id="appTest"></ul>
```

**card.js** - This is where the API is parsed and individual cards are formed

```
import { initializeClock } from './timer';

const rocketCard = (array) => {

    const cardReturn = array.map(indiv => {
    
  
        let rocketCard= `<li class='rocket-card'>
                        <img src="${indiv.rocketPhoto}" />
                        <h2>${indiv.rocketName}</h2>
                        <div class='card-body'>
                            <p class='card-subtitle'> Launch Date:</p>
                            <p>${indiv.launchDate}</p>
                            </br>
                            <p class='card-subtitle'>Launch Location: </p>
                            <p> ${indiv.location} </p>
                            <div id='countdownId'></div>
                            </br>
                            <p class='card-subtitle'>Upcoming Mission Description:</p>
                            <p class='card-desc'>${indiv.description}</p>
                            </div>
                            </li>`
        initializeClock('countdownId', indiv.launchDate)
        return rocketCard;
    })
    document
        .getElementById('appTest')
        .innerHTML = cardReturn.join('')
}

const rocketCollection = () => {
  
    let rocketArr = [];
 
    // fetch('https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Live Data subject to limits
    fetch('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Fetch stale data for development
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => response.results.forEach(indiv => (
        rocketArr.push({
        rocketName: indiv.name,
        launchDate: indiv.window_start,
        rocketPhoto: indiv.image, 
        location: indiv.pad.location.name,
        description: indiv.mission ? indiv.mission.description : 'No description available'
    }))))
  .then(() => rocketCard(rocketArr))
};
```

**timer.js** - The current functions I'm using to create the countdown timer.

```
const myTimer = (deadline) => {
    let theDeadline = new Date(deadline).getTime();
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let timeleft = theDeadline - now;
    let days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
   
    return {days, hours, minutes, seconds};
};

export const initializeClock = (id, endtime) => {
    const clock = document.getElementById(id);
    const timeinterval = setInterval(() => {
        const t = myTimer(endtime);
        clock.innerHTML =   'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                            'hours: '+ t.hours + '<br>' +
                            'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                            'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this into two parts.

First is just getting things printing out in the DOM. You correctly identified that the `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'` error was because the element wasn't inserted into the DOM yet. On top of that, I see two more problems:

1. You have a variable named `rocketCard` inside a function called `rocketCard`. You're asking for trouble there because any time you try to access that variable that holds your markup you're liable to end up calling the function on accident instead. So to keep debugging easier, I've renamed the function to something that's more inline with what it actually does: `initDom`.
2. You're using the same ID – `countdownId` – for every countdown. So even if you do get the markup inserted into the DOM correctly, things aren't going to work. We need to generate a unique ID for each countdown.

Below I've changed the `map` to a `forEach`, which *first* inserts the element into the DOM (using `innerHTML +=` instead of dumping the whole thing in at once at the end), *then* initializes the countdown.

```js
const myTimer = (deadline) => {
  let theDeadline = new Date(deadline).getTime();
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let timeleft = theDeadline - now;
  let days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  let hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  return {
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
};

const initializeClock = (id, endtime) => {
  const clock = document.getElementById(id);
  const timeinterval = setInterval(() => {
    const t = myTimer(endtime);
    clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
      'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' +
      'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
      'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

const initDom = (array) => {
  const app = document.getElementById('appTest');
  array.forEach((indiv, index) => {
    const countdownId = `countdownId-${index}`;
    const rocketCard = `<li class='rocket-card'>
      <img src="${indiv.rocketPhoto}" />
      <h2>${indiv.rocketName}</h2>
      <div class='card-body'>
        <p class='card-subtitle'> Launch Date:</p>
          <p>${indiv.launchDate}</p>
        </br>
        <p class='card-subtitle'>Launch Location: </p>
          <p>${indiv.location} </p>
          <div id="${countdownId}"></div>
        </br>
        <p class='card-subtitle'>Upcoming Mission Description:</p>
        <p class='card-desc'>${indiv.description}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    `;
    app.innerHTML += rocketCard;
    initializeClock(countdownId, indiv.launchDate);
  });
};

const createRocketCollection = () => {
  let rocketArr = [];

  //fetch('https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Live Data subject to limits
  fetch('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Fetch stale data for development
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      response.results.forEach(indiv => {
        rocketArr.push({
          rocketName: indiv.name,
          launchDate: indiv.window_start,
          rocketPhoto: indiv.image,
          location: indiv.pad.location.name,
          description: indiv.mission ? indiv.mission.description : 'No description available'
        });
      });
    })
    .then(() => initDom(rocketArr));
};

createRocketCollection();
```

```html
<ul id="appTest"></ul>
```

So now we've got stuff showing up, but our countdowns aren't actually there. What gives?

First off, you store your interval in a variable called `timeinterval`, which is good because then you can clear it later, but you never actually call `timeinterval()`.

If we fix that problem, we'll see our loop runs one time and then throws an error. But we do get one working countdown, woo!

The next problem to fix is basically that you need to keep reference to each timer outside the loop where you initially create them. There's probably lots of ways to do this, but just as an example what I've done is made an array where each item in the array corresponds to one of the rockets and contains an object that looks like `{ startInterval: () => ... }`.

After initializing the DOM, we loop back through this new array to initialize the rocket timers by calling those `startInterval` functions.

```js
let countdowns = [];

const myTimer = (deadline) => {
  let theDeadline = new Date(deadline).getTime();
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let timeleft = theDeadline - now;
  let days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  let hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  return {
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
};

const initializeClock = (id, endtime, index) => {
  return {
    startInterval: setInterval(() => {
      const clock = document.getElementById(id);
      const t = myTimer(endtime);
      clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
        'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' +
        'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
        'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
      if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdowns[index].startInterval);
      }
    }, 1000),
  };
};

const initDom = (array) => {
  const app = document.getElementById('appTest');
  array.forEach((indiv, index) => {
    const countdownId = `countdownId-${index}`;
    const rocketCard = `<li class='rocket-card'>
      <img src="${indiv.rocketPhoto}" />
      <h2>${indiv.rocketName}</h2>
      <div class='card-body'>
        <p class='card-subtitle'> Launch Date:</p>
          <p>${indiv.launchDate}</p>
        </br>
        <p class='card-subtitle'>Launch Location: </p>
          <p>${indiv.location} </p>
          <div id="${countdownId}"></div>
        </br>
        <p class='card-subtitle'>Upcoming Mission Description:</p>
        <p class='card-desc'>${indiv.description}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    `;
    app.innerHTML += rocketCard;
    const rocketClock = initializeClock(countdownId, indiv.launchDate, index);
    countdowns.push(rocketClock);
  });
};

const createRocketCollection = () => {
  let rocketArr = [];

  //fetch('https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Live Data subject to limits
  fetch('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/?limit=12') //Fetch stale data for development
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      response.results.forEach(indiv => {
        rocketArr.push({
          rocketName: indiv.name,
          launchDate: indiv.window_start,
          rocketPhoto: indiv.image,
          location: indiv.pad.location.name,
          description: indiv.mission ? indiv.mission.description : 'No description available'
        });
      });
    })
    .then(() => initDom(rocketArr));
};

createRocketCollection();
countdowns.forEach(countdown => countdown.startInterval());
```

```html
<ul id="appTest"></ul>
```

So there you have a DOM full of stuff with 10 different timers running.

Fair warning, you may need to modify this a bit. I didn't fully test it or anything, and it's a little hard to tell everything is working (particularly clearing the interval when the timer hits zero) since the launch date from the dev API is the same for every rocket, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the very descriptive explanation. I see now how I could have better approached the problem. This was from an older project I had and made up a variable name when I rewrote the code. I didn't realize I already had the variable name as a function.